# In PHP stristr search and return surrounding characters each side

Tags: php, string, text, cpu-word

In PHP I am using stristr search but I also want to return and display the surrounding characters each side of the found string, like concordancer. About 9 or 10 characters should be enough, for example:
'below' is the string I have found, but then I want to display context for my users, like this:
'if I sat below the deck'

My current code is

```
if (stristr($order, $en[$i])) {
$lit= "".$en[$i]."";
$order = str_replace($en[$i], $lit, $order, $count);
$total = $total + $count;
$sub[$loc[$i]] = $sub[$loc[$i]] + $count;
$carreau[$loc[$i]] = $carreau[$loc[$i]]."".$lit." ";
}
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like `$context = substr($order,from,length)`

How to calculate *from* and *length*?

Use [`stripos`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) (and arithmetic) to calculate *from*. Beware it isn't less than 0. Review [substr doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for the why).

Use [`strlen`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) (of the "needle") and arithmetic to determine the *length*.

Comment: DinoCoderSaurus thank you for this suggestion. I am going to try it this evening.